# noty: closable "false" not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, jquery-plugins

I am using ["needim noty"](http://needim.github.io/noty/) jquery notification plugin, I am trying to close the notification only programatically, I saw option `closable` to stop closing notification. but when I am trying  notification closing with click?

any ideas to stop closing with click and do it programmatically?

["noty plugin"](http://needim.github.io/noty/)

[Refers "closable"](https://github.com/needim/noty/issues/5)

[My Issue](https://github.com/needim/noty/issues/140)

Comment: did you managed to work it out?

Comment: I am just trying to add closable to plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something like this in the past and this is what I did:

To stop closing with click, hover and close button I changed the **template and closeWith** plugin options:

```
$.noty.defaults.closeWith = ["button"];
$.noty.defaults.template = '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span></div>';
```

This way noty will make all notifications close only when clicking on the template close button but since I removed it from the template it is not possible.

*Note that you don't need to make this the default noty behavior. You can use it only in some cases by using this options only when you need.*

To close it programmatically I used **$.noty.close(id)** and **$.noty.closeAll()** functions.
To use the first one you need the notification ID that is generated when it is created.
You can get it this way and store it to use when you need to close a specific notification.

```
$n = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
var noty_id = $n.options.id;
```

**[See this working demo for a better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/PhuMD/)**

### Edit:

To set this on the fly for only some notifications you need to pass the options like this:

```
var $n = noty({
    text: 'I have a special behaviour',
    template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span></div>',
    closeWith: ["button"]
});
```

**[See this working demo for a better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/85zzx/)**

Comment: nice, but I need to set for only some messages only. could I manage to set on fly?

Comment: @user1834809 yes you can. I added an example to my answer. See the demo. First notification you can click on it to close (default behaviour) but second one is set on the fly